# how to use console.log with Cordova and Xcode

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova

I am working on a Cordova/PhoneGap project. I tried to display js console.log in Xcode console. 
I install the cordovan-plugin-console but it is not working.
After reading lost of stackoverflow post, I came up with this code:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <script>
                function onDeviceReady() {
                    if (window.cordova.logger) {
                        window.cordova.logger.__onDeviceReady();
                    }
                }
                function init() {
                    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, true);
                }
                </script>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
                <title></title>
                <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
                <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
                -->
                <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
                <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
                <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
                <script src="cordova.js"></script>
                <!-- your app's js -->
                <script src="js/app.js"></script>
                <script src="js/factories/DeviceFactory.js"></script>
                <script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
                <script src="js/controllers/DeviceController.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body ng-app="starter" onload="init()">
                <script>
                console.log("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
                </script>
                <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
            </body>

            </html>
```

However, it is still not working.
Could anyone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Xcode's console being able to show a javascript console output but i know that you can do the same with safari dev tools, take a look at this : [safari dev tools](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html)

Comment: The data I wanna display is related to bluetooth. So I have to run the project on a actual phone.

Comment: yes you can display the dom and the console of an actual phone on the safari dev tools just look at the link i gave you you can see that on developer tab there is an actual device that is detected by safari (Elaine's iPad)

Comment: Also for anyone discovering this now you may need to quit safari boot your simulated/connected device then open safari again to see the device show up in the debug list.